# System hangs when plugging in or unplugging charger

Tags: power-management, system, charging

When I plug-in or unplug my charger on my MSI PE607Rd, Ubuntu freezes.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: First step is to EDIT your QUESTION to include the revision information on Ubuntu and mention anything else you have tried like: Does it work if you plug in before powering up? Plug in after powering up but before Ubuntu starts? How long have you had this problem? If it didn't happen before, what changed?

Answer (score 1):

I too had that problem.
First, I enabled battery icon in my laptop by using `dconf editor`.
Also I had shutdown freeze problem and to overcome that I changed the `/etc/default/grub/` setting and set `apci=force`. This resolved that problem.

And, when I finally restarted, both of the problems were resolved and also the plug in or out charger freeze problem.

Try enabling the battery icon and in grub, set `apci=force`.
This may help you. Now it's working well for me.

Answer (score 0):

## `udevadm monitor` to decipher errors unplugging AC

First boot your computer with AC plugged in. Then type `sudo udevadm monitor` wait a second and unplug the AC. Your screen will look something like this:

```
$ sudo udevadm monitor
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[5888.768785] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:3f/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/ACAD (power_supply)
KERNEL[5888.799754] add      /module/thinkpad_acpi (module)
UDEV  [5888.800544] add      /module/thinkpad_acpi (module)
KERNEL[5888.824515] remove   /module/thinkpad_acpi (module)
UDEV  [5888.824827] remove   /module/thinkpad_acpi (module)
UDEV  [5889.752862] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:3f/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/ACAD (power_supply)
KERNEL[5889.804222] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:3f/PNP0C0A:03/power_supply/BAT1 (power_supply)
UDEV  [5889.805394] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:3f/PNP0C0A:03/power_supply/BAT1 (power_supply)
```

The question is where did it stop in the above list?

## `udevadm monitor` to decipher errors plugging in AC

Next reboot your machine whilst it's running on battery. Start `sudo udevadm monitor` again. Plug in your AC and your screen will look something like this:

```
$ sudo udevadm monitor
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

-KERNEL[5905.564769] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:3f/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/ACAD (power_supply)
KERNEL[5905.597141] add      /module/thinkpad_acpi (module)
UDEV  [5905.598205] add      /module/thinkpad_acpi (module)
KERNEL[5905.624567] remove   /module/thinkpad_acpi (module)
UDEV  [5905.625432] remove   /module/thinkpad_acpi (module)
KERNEL[5906.632639] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:3f/PNP0C0A:03/power_supply/BAT1 (power_supply)
UDEV  [5906.635327] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:3f/PNP0C0A:03/power_supply/BAT1 (power_supply)
UDEV  [5906.716708] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:3f/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/ACAD (power_supply)
```

The second question is when did your machine lock up in the above list?

## Use `gedit /var/log/syslog` to review error messages

Now reboot your machine whilst it is still plugged in. Log on again and type `gedit /var/log/syslog`.

Scroll through the list to the time when your machine crashed looking for error messages:

```
Dec 15 15:43:34 alien upowerd[1685]: (upowerd:1685): UPower-Linux-WARNING **: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0004/0003:046D:2010.0007/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Dec 15 15:43:39 alien kernel: [ 5800.616352] acpi INT3400:00: Unsupported event [0x86]
Dec 15 15:43:46 alien kernel: [ 5807.735823] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D0: ca0132 DSP downloaded and running
Dec 15 15:43:46 alien kernel: [ 5807.912730] acpi INT3400:00: Unsupported event [0x86]
Dec 15 15:45:07 alien kernel: [ 5888.842935] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x50000 action 0xe frozen
Dec 15 15:45:07 alien kernel: [ 5888.842938] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x00400000, PHY RDY changed
Dec 15 15:45:07 alien kernel: [ 5888.842939] ata2: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake }
Dec 15 15:45:07 alien kernel: [ 5888.842942] ata2.00: failed command: IDENTIFY DEVICE
Dec 15 15:45:07 alien kernel: [ 5888.842944] ata2.00: cmd ec/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 12 pio 512 in
Dec 15 15:45:07 alien kernel: [ 5888.842944]          res 50/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Dec 15 15:45:07 alien kernel: [ 5888.842946] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
Dec 15 15:45:07 alien kernel: [ 5888.842949] ata2: hard resetting link
Dec 15 15:45:08 alien kernel: [ 5889.554959] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Dec 15 15:45:08 alien kernel: [ 5889.557410] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
Dec 15 15:45:08 alien kernel: [ 5889.567686] ata2: EH complete
Dec 15 15:45:08 alien kernel: [ 5889.675349] acpi INT3400:00: Unsupported event [0x86]
Dec 15 15:45:24 alien kernel: [ 5906.215059] snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC0D0: ca0132 DSP downloaded and running
Dec 15 15:45:25 alien kernel: [ 5906.503964] acpi INT3400:00: Unsupported event [0x86]
Dec 15 15:47:17 alien kernel: [ 6018.982028] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x50000 action 0xe frozen
Dec 15 15:47:17 alien kernel: [ 6018.982038] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x00400000, PHY RDY changed
Dec 15 15:47:17 alien kernel: [ 6018.982044] ata2: SError: { PHYRdyChg CommWake }
Dec 15 15:47:17 alien kernel: [ 6018.982048] ata2.00: failed command: CHECK POWER MODE
Dec 15 15:47:17 alien kernel: [ 6018.982057] ata2.00: cmd e5/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 5
Dec 15 15:47:17 alien kernel: [ 6018.982057]          res 50/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Dec 15 15:47:17 alien kernel: [ 6018.982062] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
Dec 15 15:47:17 alien kernel: [ 6018.982070] ata2: hard resetting link
Dec 15 15:47:18 alien kernel: [ 6019.697995] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Dec 15 15:47:18 alien kernel: [ 6019.700625] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
Dec 15 15:47:18 alien udisksd[2389]: Error performing housekeeping for drive /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/HGST_HTS721010A9E630_JR10004M303XVF: Error updating SMART data: Error sending ATA command CHECK POWER MODE: Unexpected sense data returned:#0120000: 70 00 05 00  00 00 00 0a  00 50 00 00  21 04 00 00    p........P..!...#0120010: 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00    ................#012 (g-io-error-quark, 0)
Dec 15 15:47:18 alien kernel: [ 6019.710827] ata2: EH complete
```

In my case I see error messages but my laptop didn't lock up. Because I have a long list of error messages I already need to clean up and because I never run on the laptop on battery, I'll just ignore these errors.

## Take your notes and "Google it"

Google search is a great help in finding other people with the same problem and solutions to it.

- Copy and paste error messages into your google search bar.
- Append "Ubuntu Linux" to the end of the search string.
- Strip out unique numbers like time of day or seconds within the system log.
- Focus on search results from Ask Ubuntu, Launchpad.net and ArchLinux first.